# using LINQ to Twitter to read public tweets, do i need to register my app at Twitter

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to read tweets from a public account (the public twitter account shows delays in the public transport).

I am planning to use LINQ to Twitter for that reason.

The question is: do I need to create an 'application' at the Twitter dev portal for this reason?

This doesn't seem necessary because my custom app does not post any data but only reads it...

Answer (score 0):

Twitter recently shut down API v1.0 and everything now runs on API v1.1, including LINQ to Twitter. API v1.1 requires authentication on all endpoints.

So, you will have to create an application and use OAuth.

There are demos with the LINQ to Twitter [Downloads](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/releases/view/107832) and with the downloadable [Source](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt) code. There is a [Samples](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples&referringTitle=Home) page for various technologies. You can also read the [Documentation](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation), which includes explanations of all APIs. I recently added a [Twitter API Map](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Twitter%20API%20Map&referringTitle=Making%20API%20Calls) so you can match Twitter API endpoints with LINQ to Twitter queries.